# Gradually migrating struts1.1 to spring mvc. How to Integrate apache tiles in struts1.1

Tags: spring-mvc, struts-1

we are woking on gradually migrating struts1.1 to spring mvc. In this process we need to replace apache struts tiles with apache tiles. how do we integrate apache tiles in strutsframework(struts1.1)

Comment: Can you add more details, e.g. what you have done so far, some code snippets, etc. This will help us understand and hopefully provide help

Comment: we just started how can we keep struts while migrating to spring mvc(3.1) gradually. so far we added spring mvc configuration in our web app.. which will be using apache tiles.And want to keep current struts which is using  struts tiles need to replace with apache tiles.